# Is it possible to create dynamic HTTP Handlers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, https, server, httphandler

I've browsed through a ton of the material here at Stackoverflow and you've all done an amazing job of answering all the questions I've had. However, I am currently writing my own handlers for my HTTPS servers and I was wondering if there are a way to instantiate the handlers dynamically. Currently I have to pass the class itself to the server to create the server. This means that the global variable of the version will be the same for all. The solution would be to write handlers for each of the servers since they all share the same handler except for the server version name and GET methods. Here is my question:

Is there a way to dynamically create the handlers and pass them? I've tried to wrap the handler class in another class like so:

```
class Virtual_Handler(object):

    class Virtual_Service_Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
        #normal handler stuff
```

Of course there are a couple variables I am passing to each handler to make them different such as the get method, etc. At any rate when I create an pool of handlers in this fashion:

```
for i in range(3):
    handlers[i] = Virtual_Handler()
```

All of the

```
handlers[i].Virtual_Service_Handler
```

point to the same memory address. Which means that they are the same instance of the object. Is there something I am missing? Is it not possible to create the handler dynamically even after wrapping it in another class?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: I am creating several HTTPS servers that each serve different SSL certificates and each replies with their own server_version. It only makes sense to create a factory of http handlers as opposed to have to write 200 of them manually when the only thing changing are the certificates, server_version and sometimes the GET method.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you intend to use these classes?  You could certainly create a factory function that returns a new handler class every time you call it, but you will still need to pass a handler class (and not an instance of one) to each server.

Comment: I am attempting to pass the handler class in this statement. handlers[i].Virtual_Service_Handler it does not work however as all of the handlers have the same address. Here is a snippet of the code where I pass the handlers **VS_servers[number] = VS_host(ports[number], certs[number], keys[number], handlers[number].VSHandler, name= str(number))**

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a nested class.  Just make `virtual_handler` a *function* that you call to get a new class.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go! I am getting different addresses for each of the classes using your suggestion to use a function to return a class. Once I get it working feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you!